# recursive program that returns true if two lists share at least one node

Tags: list, recursion, nodes

say two lists are joined if they share at least one node. how can i write a recursive program

static boolean isJoined (Node L, Node LL)

such that the program returns true if the lists are joined

Comment: You question is to vague. What have you tried? What is the node class? What language? What is a shared node (key only entire node)?

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I'm new to this. It's in java. I'm essentially trying to write a method that checks if two linked lists are merged or not.

Comment: I'm a C# guy, but in C# i would write a function that flatten the Nodes. Then you could easily loop through the flattened structure to check if the lists are joined.